# Validation dangerous : get value of a text area

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-3.5

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" 
  ValidateRequest="false" 
  MasterPageFile="~/PersonPage/ConfigPersonalPage.master" 
  AutoEventWireup="true"
  CodeFile="ConfighPropertise.aspx.cs" 
  Inherits="PersonPage_ConfighPropertise" %>

<textarea style="width:850px;height:500px" 
   id="txtEnterProject"  
   name="txtEnterProject"></textarea><br />

   var a= $("#txtEnterProject").val()
```

if a=='a' there is no error

but

if a=`<p>a</p>` then the error is:

```
`error:HttpRquestValidationException:A potentially dangerous...  `
```

asp.net '3.5'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET does not like to have HTML posted by default:

**HttpRquestValidationException:**
The exception that is thrown when a potentially malicious input string is received from the client as part of the request data. EG html or script.

This is to prevent users could post malicious code to your application.

if your application runs in a **trusted environment like an intranet** then you could add the rule:

```
 <pages validateRequest=”false” />
```

to your  (asp.net 2.0, 3.5) web config to avoid this exception or for (4.0 websites):

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode=”2.0″ />
```

**[more here...](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/request-validation)**

for the other environments (like the whole internet) **do not turn this off** but **validate** and **reformat** your postbackdata in a server-valid way.

**[more here...](http://dustyreagan.com/how-to-submit-html-without-disabling/)**

sample:

**2.0/3.5:**

```
<configuration>
 ....
    <pages validateRequest="false">
    </pages>
 ....
 </configuration>
```

**4.0:**

```
<configuration>
....
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
   </system.web>
   <pages validateRequest="false">
   </pages>
....
</configuration>
```

Comment: <httpRuntime requestValidationMode=”2.0″ />
inner tag <system.web> does not  property 'requestValidationMode'